# Weird lines and smaller height

Tags: print-quality, diy-3d-printer

I finished my first print and it came out like this

[image: Print side]

[image: Print second side]

[image: Print top side]

I calibrated all my axis steps and manual movement gives perfect numbers.

I am printing with these slicer settings:

> [image: Slicer settings]
>
> [image: Slicer speed settings]

I don't even know where is the problem to begin searching for a solution. It's my very first print after a couple fails and a lot of calibration to Z axis and bed leveling.

Update the printer without the heatbed as it's an older picture:

[image: 3D printer]

The Z axis moves on 2 lead screws and 2 rods with bearings all of which attached to the plate.

Comment: please tell us the printer design or show a picture of it

Comment: It's a diy printer i am not near it rn to take a pic but i updated with a photo without the heatbed which is on the white plate basically

Comment: Your X belt needs more tension. Also you move a lot of weight (rods, aluminium plates, X stepper). The X belt does not power the carriage in the centre, you only have 2 bearings while you should use 3. All this adds to the (in)accuracy of the print. Also add a picture from the side please. It might be that the platform is too heavy that you are missing steps.

Comment: i will add a side picture once i go to the printer. what do you mean x belt doesn't power the carriage and how can i minimize all those errors for example if i added 3 bearings instead of 2 would it matter?

Comment: Using 2 small bearings and attaching the belt closer to one bearing may cause the carriage  to rotate and prevent smooth movement, a third bearing or a longer one prevents that. Please also explain by [edit] of your question in words how the platform moves; e.g. do you have 4 leadscrews raising the platform, how are they powered.

Comment: Ok are we talking about the same axis here: the axis with just 1 belt if yes then i dont understand where would i put a third bearing and nothing rotates there
if not then we are talking about the axis with 2 belts? and u are talking like there is just one belt so i think i am misunderstanding you a little

Comment: How do the  measured X, Y, and Z dimensions of your printed cube compare with the model? Is the Z shorter than anticipated?

Comment: yes Z is shorter by 2mm x and y are the expected sizes

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that your axis aren't square, aren't tightened enough and you seem to have overextrusion as well. That would explain why all your layers are wobbly and not neatly stacked on top of each other, why your cube is far being being a cube (the picture of the X face shows it clearly) and the quality of surface finish on the top.

I do not know what kind of printer you are using, but I would advise you to check that the X and Y axis are correctly calibrated and that they're perfectly square, which would ensure that each layer is correctly stacked on top of the previous one to produce a nice cube. And make sure to tighten the axles to avoid the noise in the print due to the vibration produced by the printing.

As for the overextrusion, you'll need to make more test with your printer and the material you're using, changing temperature, and print speed until you find the right combination that will extrude just enough material through your nozzle.

Comment: Thank you i will make sure to check all of that
about the extrusion how exactly do i set that is it in marlin or is it from pronterface because it's confusing me a little

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot help further as I do not use marlin or pronterface with my printer, thus I'm not familiar with how they work.

Comment: This looks like substantial amounts of overextrusion, I'd try fixing that problem before anything else. Change the steps/mm for the E axis in Marlin, there's extrusion tuning tutorials out there that can help you figure out how to get a good extrusion rate. Hint, you've got your steps/mm in the E axis set too high.

Comment: but when i searched regards the steps/mm every guide said cold extrude and measure the filament if it's the same number then the steps are fine and i am extruding exactly what i am giving the machine or is that can change sometimes?